# Fetch data from a large azure table and how to avoid timeout error?

Tags: python-3.x, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I am trying to fetch data from a large Azure Table and after few hours running into the following error:

```
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

The following is my code :

```
from azure.storage import TableService,Entity
from azure import *
import json
from datetime import datetime as dt
from datetime import timezone, timedelta
ts=TableService(account_name='dev',account_key='key')

i=0

next_pk=None
next_rk=None

N=10
date_N_days_ago = datetime.now(timezone.utc) -timedelta(days=N)


while True:
     entities=ts.query_entities('Events',next_partition_key=next_pk,next_row_key=next_rk,top=1000)
     i+=1
     with open('blobdata','a') as fil:
         for entity in entities:
            if (entity.Timestamp) > date_N_days_ago:

                fil.write(str(entity.DetailsJSON)+'\n')

     with open('1k_data','a') as fil2:

         if i%5000==0:
            fil2.write('{}|{}|{}|{}'.format(i,entity.PartitionKey, entity.Timestamp,entity.DetailsJSON+'\n'))
    if hasattr(entities,'x_ms_continuation'):
        x_ms_continuation=getattr(entities,'x_ms_continuation')
        next_pk=x_ms_continuation['nextpartitionkey']
        next_rk=x_ms_continuation['nextrowkey']
    else:
        break;
```

Also, if someone has a better idea of how to achieve this process in a better fashion please do tell as the table is very large and the code is taking too long to process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exception can happen in all sorts of network calls on occasion. It should be entirely transient. I would recommend simply catching the error, waiting a little bit, and trying again.

The [Azure Storage Python Library](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python) recently moved and we will be doing a ton of improvements on it in the coming months including built-in retry policies. So, in the future the library itself will retry these sorts of errors for you.

In general if you want to make this faster you could try adding some multithreading to the processing of your entities. Even parallelizing writing to the two different files could really help.